# Calling if else output to other script

Tags: matlab, function, if-statement

I have written a function called "tension.m" in which I have used if else condition as shown below.

```
function [T,T_earlyvalues,T_latervalues] = tension(u,sigma,G,N,K)
%the values of sigma,G,N,K can be taken arbitrary.
sigma=2; G=3;N=8;K=1; v=1;
w=2.2;
if u<w
  T =v*sqrt(sigma+G^2/(N-K));
  T_earlyvalues=T;
else
  T=(2*v)*sqrt(sigma+G^2/(N+K));
  T_latervalues=T;
end
```

Now in another script "myvalues.m" I need to call T_earlyvalues and T_latervalues separately.

```
%have some coding before this part
sigma0=2400; lambda=1.3; v=2; sigma=2; G=3;N=8;K=1;  
u=0:0.01:5;  
T=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);
T_earlyvalues=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);
T_latervalues=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);
deltaA=T_earlyvalues*sigma0*pi;
deltaB=T_latervalue*lambda*pi/2;
%have some coding after this part
```

How could I call the said values which are under if-else statement from tension.m function to myvalues.m script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be a number of issues here, not the least of which is some confusion about how output argument lists work when defining or calling functions. I suggest starting with [this documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) to better understand how to create and call functions. *However*, this issue is somewhat moot because the larger problem is how you are using your [conditional statement](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/if.html)...

You are trying to pass a *vector* `u` to your function `tension`, and from what I can tell you want to return a vector `T`, where the values of `T` for `u < w` are computed with a different formula than the values of `T` for `u >= w`. Your conditional statement will not accomplish this for you. Instead, you will want to use [logical indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/) to write your function like so:

```
function [T, index] = tension(u, sigma, G, N, K)
  T = zeros(size(u));  % Initialize T to a vector of zeroes
  w = 2.2;
  index = (u < w);  % A logical vector, with true where u < w, false where u >= w
  T(index) = u(index)*v*sqrt(sigma+G^2/(N-K));       % Formula for u < w
  T(~index) = 2*(u(~index)-v)*sqrt(sigma+G^2/(N+K));  % Formula for u >= w
end
```

Now you can call this function, capturing the second output argument to use for identifying "early" versus "late" values:

```
sigma0 = 2400; lambda = 1.3; v = 2; sigma = 2; G = 3; N = 8; K = 1;
u = 0:0.01:5;
[T, earlyIndex] = tension(u, sigma, G, N, K);  % Call function
T_earlyvalues = T(earlyIndex);   % Use logical index to get early T values
T_latervalues = T(~earlyIndex);  % Use negated logical index to get later T values
```

And you can then use the subvectors `T_earlyvalues` and `T_latervalues` however you like.

Comment: thanks for your reply. the code is working fine with the given function. I am sorry that I typed the equation incorrectly. I tried to modify it in my function but I am getting error for that. `T(index) = u*v*sqrt(sigma+G^2/(N-K));       % Formula for u < w` and `T(~index) = (2*(u-v))*sqrt(sigma+G^2/(N+K));  % Formula for u >= w` I am getting the following error; "In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same."

Comment: @Jack: You have to index `u` with `index` in your formulas, as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the updated answer. The updated answer is working for the condition of `u<w` but not for the `u>w`. I am getting the same error `In an assignment  A(:) = B, the number of elements in A and B must be the same.` for `T(~index) = 2*(u(index)-v)*sqrt(sigma+G^2/(N+K));  % Formula for u >= w`

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the `tension` function such that it returns three outputs.

If you call that function by requiring only one output, the function returns the first value, in your case, `T`

This implies that

```
T=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);
```

shoud work since `T` is the first output parameter

```
T_earlyvalues=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);
T_latervalues=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);
```

are not working, since, actually `tension` returns the first value (`T`, whjikle you are expecting the second and the third respectively.)

You can cahnge the two above calls this way:

```
[~,T_earlyvalues,~]=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);
[~,~,T_latervalues]=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);
```

The `~` allows to avoid the function return the output paraemter.

You can find [additional information here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/ignore-function-outputs.html)

Notice that in your function `T_earlyvalue` is not set in the `else` block, same for `T_latervalue` in the `if` block.

This will generate an error such as

> Output argument T_earlyvalue (and maybe others) not assigned during call to tension

or

> Output argument T_latervalues (and maybe others) not assigned during call to tension

You can initialize the output values to default values, at the beginning of the function, for example:

```
T=NaN
T_earlyvalue=NaN
T_latervalues=NaN
```

You can then use these special values (or any other you want to use) to trace, for example, if the `if` block has been executed or the `else`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have corrected the typing error. I tried replacing as follows but I am getting an error;

        T=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);  
        [~,T_earlyvalues,~]=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);
        [~,~,T_latervalues]=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);
        deltaA=T_earlyvalues*sigma0*pi;
        deltaB=T_latervalues*lambda*pi/2;

I am getting the following error,


Output argument "T_earlyvalues" (and maybe others) not assigned during call to "tension".

Error in myvalues (line 7)
  [~,T_earlyvalues,~]=tension(u,sigma,G,N,K);

Comment: You can fix the error by initializing the output variables (`T=NaN`, `T_earlyvalue=NaN`, `T_latervalues=NaN`, or to any other default value, `T=-999`, `T_earlyvalue=-999`, `T_latervalues=-999`) at the beginning of the function body.